# SpringBoot with openapi-generator-maven-plugin issue. Getting "No operations defined in spec"

Tags: spring-boot, openai-api, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I am trying to follow API first approach and defined api specification in yml file. Code generation, compilation is fine. Tomcat is coming up fine but  I am getting "No operations defined in spec!" My POM looks like following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>xxx.yyyyyyy</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-openapi-codegenerator</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test-openapi-codegenerator</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-rc2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>
                                ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/swagger/testapi.yml
                            </inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <apiPackage>com.openapi.springboot.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>com.openapi.springboot.dto</modelPackage>
                            <supportingFilesToGenerate>
                                ApiUtil.java
                            </supportingFilesToGenerate>
                            <configOptions>
                                <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                                <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
                                <useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I am expecting to see my API in swagger but getting "No operations defined in spec!".

My API Specification

```
openapi: "3.0.1"

info:
  title: "User"
  version: "1"
  description: User API

servers:
  - url: http://localhost:8080/api
    description: Local server

paths:

  /user:
    post:
      summary: Save User
      operationId: saveUser
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/UserDTO'
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/UserDTO'

  /user/{id}:
    get:
      summary: Get User By Id
      operationId: getUserById
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path
          description: Unique Id of an User
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
            format: uuid
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/UserDTO'

components:
  schemas:
    UserDTO:
      type: object
      description: Data element for User
      required:
        - email
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
          format: uuid
        email:
          type: string
        firstName:
          type: string
          minLength: 3
        lastName:
          type: string

    Error:
      type: object
      properties:
        code:
          type: integer
          format: int32
        message:
          type: string
```

Comment: Guess, you have an error in your api spec. Maybe "operation is not defined"?

Comment: Added my api spec above.

Comment: It works when I test with your provided files. So the error seems to be in some additional files not shared in the post. Maybe you can post a Minimal Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example